# Type-specific functions for immutable generic classes

Tags: scala, generics, types, containers

Say I have a `Container_Generic[T]` generic class and I want specific `functions` to be available to it only if `T` is `Double` for example.

Is there a way to do that without mutability or creating sub-classes?

The reason I ask is because sub-classes require a lot of unnecessary code repetition. See example below:

```
class Container_Generic[T](x: Seq[T]){
  def map(f: T => T): Container_Generic[T] = new Container_Generic[T](x map f)
  // def max: Double = x.max //<-Impossible to implement unless T pre-specified
}

class Container_Double_works(x: Seq[Double]) extends Container_Generic[Double](x){
  override def map(f: Double => Double): Container_Double_works = new Container_Double_works(x map f)
  def max: Double = x.max
}

class Container_Double_doesntWork(x: Seq[Double]) extends Container_Generic[Double](x){
  def max: Double = x.max
}

// Work
val C_base = new Container_Generic[Int](Seq(1)).map(_*2) // : Container_Generic[Int]
val C_double = new Container_Double_works(Seq(1)).map(_*2) // : Container_Double_works

// Don't work correctly: No longer same class
val C_double_doesntWork = new Container_Double_doesntWork(Seq(1)).map(_*2) // : Container_Generic
```

I am still new to Scala, so I may be taking the wrong approach, or perhaps just don't know the correct term for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do almost everithing with Scala impicits

```
class Container_Generic[T](val x: Seq[T]) {
    def map(f: T => T): Container_Generic[T] = new Container_Generic[T](x map f)
}

implicit class WithMax(val c: Container_Generic[Double]) {
    def max: Double = c.x.max
}

val cDouble: Container_Generic[Double] = new Container_Generic(Seq(1.12))
val cString: Container_Generic[String] = new Container_Generic(Seq("12"))
println(cDouble.max)
//won't compile
//  println(cString.max)
```

Comment: You can remove `toBetterType` if you mark `WithMax` as implicit.

Comment: It works, but not on top level. It will give `'implicit' modifier cannot be used for top-level objects` error otherwise. Good answer though.